# Algebra with Surds

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I'm hoping someone can help me understand where I'm going wrong with this question.

Solve the equation: $$\frac{3^{5x+2}} {9^{1-x}} = \frac{27^{4+3x}}{729}$$

My working:

Make all terms powers of 3 $$\frac{3^{5x+2}} {(3^2)^{1-x}} = \frac{(3^3)^{4+3x}}{3^6}$$
Multiply out the indices $$\frac{3^{5x+2}} {3^{2-2x}} = \frac{3^{12+9x}}{3^6}$$
Work the indices only $$\frac{5x+2} {2-2x} = \frac{12+9x}{6}$$
Simplify as $-2.5x = 2+1.5x$ then $-5x =4 + 3x$ and so $-8x = 4$ and then $x = -1/2$

The book tells me the correct answer is $x = -3$

Thanks in advance

Gary

Comment: Tittensor, is that you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $$\frac{3^{5x+2}} {3^{2-2x}} = \frac{3^{12+9x}}{3^6}$$
you work out the indices to get
$$
3^{(5x+2) - (2-2x) - (12+9x) + 6}=1=3^0,
$$
and thus
$$(5x+2) - (2-2x) - (12+9x) + 6=0$$

Can you finish this?

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. Yes, I can get to $x=-3$ from there. So the tool I was missing was to multiply both sides by $$\frac {3^6} {3^{12+9x}}$$ to get the RHS to equal 1.